# Consumindo webservice, tela de login

Tags: web-service, express.js, request

Bom dia!

To criando um projeto em JS, EJS e Express.js para estudos, para consumir uma listagem de carros usando o webservice: 
https://carros-springboot.herokuapp.com/api/v1/carros

Na tela de login, usando: https://carros-springboot.herokuapp.com/api/v2/login

Preciso pegar o token JWT, preciso mandar um post method com user e password.

Tem os passos nesse site: http://ricardolecheta.com.br/?p=1106

Enfim, usei poucas vezes o recurso npm "request", precisava saber só se pelo menos estou no caminho certo.

Segue o código:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

// Post
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let user = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;

  let options = {
    url: "https://carros-springboot.herokuapp.com/api/v2/login",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
  };

  request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    let carUser = JSON.parse(username.body);
    let carPassword = JSON.parse(password.body);
    alert(carUser);
    alert(carPassword);
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="/" method="post" class="form-signin">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Login</h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
  <input type="username" id="inputUser" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus name="username">
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required name="password">
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Seria mais ou menos isso?
Alguem da um help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Posts
app.post("/", (req, res) => {

  // Data from login input
  let user = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let token_jwt = "";

  // Fetching data with the webserver
  let data = {
    username: user,
    password: password
  };

  // Stringifying the data
  let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

  // Request params
  let options = {
    url: loginURL,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
       "Authorization": `Bearer ${token_jwt}`
     },
    body: jsonData
  };

  // Requesting data
  request(options, (err, resp, body) => {
    if(err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
        token_jwt = resp.body.token;
        console.log(token_jwt);
        console.log(body);
        res.redirect("/home");
      } else {
        console.log("Error, please try again.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Tá, bati a cabeça pra caramba mas deu certo, funcionou!
Agora preciso pegar esse token do response e salva-lo em localStorage.
Alguem da um help?

Answer (score 0):

Ta! Já vi que tava tudo errado...

O post seria mais ou menos isso:

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let user = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let token_jwt = "";

  request.post({
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token_jwt}`
    },
    "url": loginURL,
    "body": JSON.stringify({
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "123"
    })
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    if(err){
      return console.log(err);
    } else {
      if(user === body.username && password === body.password){
        token_jwt = res.body.token;
        console.log(token_jwt);
        console.log("Successfully logged in!");
        res.redirect("/home");
      }

    }
  });
```

Certo?